# Using PHP Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to get a PHP JSON variable in my JS function:

```
    var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( ' + <?php echo $latLongJson; ?> + ' );
```

The PHP code which is fetching me the latLongJson variable is :

```
<?php
    $latLongJson = $dbUrl->getCoordinates($id);
    print_r($latLongJson);
?>
```

I am able to print latLongJson variable using PHP. But console.log for json_obj says it is undefined.

JS Code

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( ' + <?php echo $latLongJson; ?> + ' );
    //var json_obj = 1;
    //]]>
    console.log(json_obj);
</script>
```

Generated JS Code:

```
//<![CDATA[
var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( ' +  + ' );
//]]>
console.log(json_obj);
```

Comment: Can you print the value you are trying to parse? It's probably mis-formatted.

Comment: What is the *exact* generated js code? Copy-paste it as-is from the page body

Comment: it could be that the JSON is not formatted correctly. you might want to show the JSON that $latLongJson is supposed to be

Comment: JSON is correct, i used json_encode to prepare that JSON and validated it on JSONLint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what `' + <?php echo $latLongJson; ?> + '` becomes when `$latLongJson` is valid.

For example, say that $latLongJson contains the string `{"foo": "bar"}`, then you are calling:

```
jQuery.parseJSON ( ' + {"foo": "bar"} + ' );
```

When you just want:

```
jQuery.parseJSON ( '{"foo": "bar"}' );
```

You can remove the `+` to get it to work, but you don't normally* need to parse JSON in Javascript anyway. If you know that `$latLongJson` contains valid JSON, you can just do:

```
var json_obj = <?php echo $latLongJson; ?>;
```

*[There is an exception](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset)

Comment: Ok, so the thing is i am trying to create a PHP API of my service. The endpoint gives me a JSON. I want to consume that JSON using JS code. Both on same domain.

Comment: i didn't even see the + signs.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Judging from your edit it looks like `$latLongJson` is empty. Make sure that `$latLongJson = $dbUrl->getCoordinates($id);` is before the `var json_obj = ...` line.